# Redux set initial state as API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

I am creating a site to show some phones and have set up an API to pass back the latest phones from my database. In my component within the componentWillMount I am dispatching an action that will then fetch the API results and populate my store. The component then renders what is in the store.

This seems to be all be working ok, but does mean that there is some time when nothing is showing while the API call is being made.

I was wondering if there is some way to either dispatch the action on the server and set the initialState to be API response, or some other way to pass the API response from the server to the client, so that the data is there already when the component renders?

This is what I have so far...

**Reducers**

```
export function latestPhonesHasErrored(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LATEST_PHONES_HAS_ERRORED':
            return action.latestPhonesHasErrored;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function latestPhonesIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LATEST_PHONES_IS_LOADING':
            return action.latestPhonesIsLoading;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function latestPhones(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LATEST_PHONES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.latestPhones;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
export function latestPhonesFetchData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(latestPhonesIsLoading(true));

        fetch('/api/latest-phones/')
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(latestPhonesIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((results) => 
dispatch(latestPhonesFetchDataSuccess(results)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(latestPhonesHasErrored(true)))
    }
}
```

**Server.js**

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        match({routes, location: req.originalUrl}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
            if(!err) {
                const html = this.render(renderProps);

                res.render('index', {
                    content: html,
                    pageTitle: 'title',
                    description: 'description',
                    canonical: 'canonical'
                });
            } else {
                res.status(500).send();
            }
        });
    });

render(renderProps) {
    let html = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
        </Provider>
    );
    return html;
}
```

**Component**

```
import {latestPhonesFetchData} from '../../../actions/results-actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        latestPhones: state.latestPhones
    }
};

class Home extends Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.latestPhonesFetchData(); 
    }

    render(){
        /* all component render here*/
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {latestPhonesFetchData})(Home);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: since it's asynchronous there's no guarantee that you can have the data there before the component loads, you're better off just having a loading screen and updating the loading screen when the data loads.

Comment: Yes I have done this in other places on my site where I have API requests, but I was hoping there was some way I could pass the correct initial state in this case where there requires no user interaction so that Google would also be able to crawl the content for SEO purposes

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering React on the client (which you are), then there isn't a way to pre-load the data before the component renders. @A.Lau's comment above is correct ... your best option is to render a loading spinner or some equivalent while the data is being fetched.

Alternatively, you can use server-side rendering. This means rendering React ahead of time and serving an HTML file to the client. By rendering on the server, you can just grab the data you need from your database, and pass it in as props to the component before rendering. No AJAX required, and you never have to show a loading view to the client.

Comment: Do you have any good tutorials or examples of server side rendering you recommend? I feel it may be more useful for me to go down that route as I would like the SEO benefit of having the content loading.